# Left Join Three Tables, Combine Name Fields into one Column

Tags: mysql, sql

We have three types of users in our database. We are trying to generate a report. And I can left join them together. But if I do it that way I have three first name, and three last name columns. How do I combine data from all three into the one column.

```
SELECT e_job.objId AS 'Job Number', e_student.Lastname, e_student.Name, e_teachers.Lastname, e_teachers.Name, e_supportStaff.Lastname, e_supportStaff.Name
FROM e_job
LEFT JOIN e_student ON e_job.jName = e_student.username
LEFT JOIN e_teachers ON e_job.jName = e_teachers.username
LEFT JOIN e_supportStaff ON e_job.jName = e_supportStaff.username WHERE jStatus != 2 && jStatus != 7 && jStatus != -1
```

The current output displays 7 columns, with a first as last name for each type of user.

How do I combine the last 6 columns so all the First Names are in 1 and the Last Names within another.

```
-------------------------------------
|Job Number |Last Name  |Fist Name  |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|1          |Doe        |John       |
|2          |Test       |Test       |
|3          |Test 2     |Test2      |
-------------------------------------
```

Thank you

Comment: What database is it? (it makes a difference to available solutions). Always include type of database in tags.

Comment: mysql sorry I didn't realise.

Comment: **by the way** don't use single quotes for identities, use them for values. e.g Use double quotes for **AS "Last Name"** but personally I never use column names with spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic solution could be a union query like this:

```
SELECT e_job.objId AS "Job Number", e_student.Lastname AS "Job Number", e_student.Name AS "First Name"
FROM e_job
INNER JOIN e_student ON e_job.jName = e_student.username

UNION

SELECT e_job.objId AS 'Job Number', e_teachers.Lastname, e_teachers.Name
FROM e_job
INNER JOIN e_teachers ON e_job.jName = e_teachers.username

UNION

SELECT e_job.objId AS 'Job Number', e_supportStaff.Lastname, e_supportStaff.Name
FROM e_job
INNER JOIN e_supportStaff ON e_job.jName = e_supportStaff.username WHERE jStatus != 2 && jStatus != 7 && jStatus != -1
```

Note the left joins have changed to inner joins becase we no no longer need to cater to the other tables, and with inner joins we only get rows that have matching data.

An alternative, if you wish to differentiate between the types of people, then introduce another column and change to using UNION ALL

```
SELECT e_job.objId AS "Job Number", 'Student' as Type, e_student.Lastname AS "Job Number", e_student.Name AS "First Name"
FROM e_job
INNER JOIN e_student ON e_job.jName = e_student.username

UNION ALL

SELECT e_job.objId AS 'Job Number', 'Teacher' as Type, e_teachers.Lastname, e_teachers.Name
FROM e_job
INNER JOIN e_teachers ON e_job.jName = e_teachers.username

UNION ALL

SELECT e_job.objId AS 'Job Number', 'Support' as Type, e_supportStaff.Lastname, e_supportStaff.Name
FROM e_job
INNER JOIN e_supportStaff ON e_job.jName = e_supportStaff.username WHERE jStatus != 2 && jStatus != 7 && jStatus != -1
```

nb:
UNION, when used by itself, removes duplicate rows from the result (and hence can be slower than UNION ALL which does NOT remove duplicate rows). In my second query you cant duplicate a row from any of the 3 subqueries because column 2 is different in each of those, and UNION ALL makes sense.